# How can you reformat C source code '{' placements in VIM?

Tags: vim

I want to change the following code:

```
if (test)
{
       statements;
}
else
{
       statements;
}
```

To the following:

```
if (test) {
       statements;
} else {
       statements;
}
```

Using '=' doesn't do this function (as far as I can tell).
Is there any clever VIM command to do this?

Comment: Use something like `indent` or `astyle`

Comment: Just for the case it is not obvious for the OP: what @FDinoff is referring to are command line tools that allow re-indenting C source code according to a set of rules. Sometimes it is hard to get the options right, but after you do the changes are done in a heart beat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with regexes. Here, it will be:

```
:%s/\_s*{/ {/g
:%s/}\zs\_s*\ze\(else\|while\)/ /g
```

The secret is in `/\_s` which is like `/\s` (which matches spaces), but which also matches newlines.

If you also want to transform things like `{ return foo; }`, you'll have to insert newlines as well, and then reindent everything.

```
:%s/\_s*{\_s*/ {\r/g
gg=G
```

You can also have a look at vim plugins that integrates tools like AStyle or clang-format which should give better results.

PS: [lh-cpp](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp) and mu-template snippets have an option (through [`:AddStyle`](https://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhDev#Formatting_of_brackets_characters)) that lets the end-user specify whether a newline shall be inserted or not. Sometimes, the better approach is to produce code that conforms to project style.